# Error in Visual Studio, curly braces do not match

Tags: c#

I get the following error message in Visual Studio on Mac OS **"Error CS1513, } expected"**. For some reasons one of the curly braces pairs do not connect. I have activated format upon saving-setting but the error persists.

```
using System;
namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public Movie()
        {
            public object MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `public object MyProperty { get; set; }` should be outside the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper braces:

```
using System;
namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public Movie()
        {
        } // <- this was missing

        public object MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
    // <-removed one here
}
```